# Writing AVRO data with python to Kafka and consume with Clickhouse Kafka Engine table

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, clickhouse

I try to write a dictionary in python to Kafka and I want to consume it with a Clickhouse Kafka Engine table. If I write the dictionary to an avro file everything is working. But if I try to send it via Kafka Clickhouse gives me the error:

```
2022.07.25 14:55:40.111381 [ 4421 ] {} <Error> void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t): std::exception. Code: 1001, type: avro::Exception, e.what() = Invalid data file. Magic does not match: , Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
```

My avro schema looks like:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"acct_data",
  "fields":[
    {"name":"mac_src","type":"string"},
    {"name":"mac_dst","type":"string"},
    {"name":"peer_ip_src","type":"string"},
    {"name":"ip_src","type":"string"},
    {"name":"ip_dst","type":"string"},
    {"name":"port_src","type":"int"},
    {"name":"port_dst","type":"int"},
    {"name":"tcp_flags","type":"int"},
    {"name":"ip_proto","type":"int"},
    {"name":"timestamp_start","type":"long"},
    {"name":"timestamp_end","type":"long"},
    {"name":"ip_prot_ver","type":"int"},
    {"name":"in_phys_int","type":"long"},
    {"name":"dot1q_cvlan","type":"long"},
    {"name":"dot1q_vlan","type":"long"},
    {"name":"out_phys_int","type":"long"},
    {"name":"post_dot1q_cvlan","type":"long"},
    {"name":"post_dot1q_vlan","type":"long"},
    {"name":"in_vrfid","type":"int"},
    {"name":"packets","type":"long"},
    {"name":"bytes","type":"long"}
    ]
}
```

And my python script to write the data is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import avro.schema
import io
from avro.schema import parse
from avro.io import DatumWriter, DatumReader, BinaryEncoder, BinaryDecoder
from confluent_kafka import Producer


# initialize kafka producer
producer_settings = {'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka-zoo01.sisrdev.agw:9093,kafka-zoo02.sisrdev.agw:9093,kafka-zoo03.sisrdev.agw:9093','api.version.request': False }
p = Producer(producer_settings)

# read avro schema
schema = parse(open("./schema.avsc", "rb").read())

# message dict
ipfix_data = {'mac_src': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 'mac_dst': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 'peer_ip_src': '111.111.111.111', 'ip_src': '111.111.111.111', 'ip_dst': '111.111.111.111', 'port_src': 42993, 'port_dst': 42993, 'tcp_flags': 0, 'ip_proto': 6, 'timestamp_start': 1657636311802, 'timestamp_end': 1657636311802, 'ip_prot_ver': 4, 'in_phys_int': 1342177357, 'dot1q_cvlan': 0, 'dot1q_vlan': 0, 'out_phys_int': 103120896, 'post_dot1q_cvlan': 0, 'post_dot1q_vlan': 0, 'in_vrfid': 32, 'packets': 1, 'bytes': 1474}

# serialize the message data using the schema
buf = io.BytesIO()
encoder = BinaryEncoder(buf)
writer = DatumWriter(schema)
writer.write(ipfix_data, encoder)
buf.seek(0)
message_data = (buf.read())

# Send the serialized message to the Kafka topic
p.produce('avro_test', message_data)
p.flush()
```

The Clickhouse SQL to create the table are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.kafka_avro_consumer ON CLUSTER "ch-cluster" (
        mac_src String,
        mac_dst String,
        peer_ip_src String,
        ip_src String,
        ip_dst String,
        port_src UInt16,
        port_dst UInt16,
        tcp_flags UInt16,
        ip_proto UInt8,
        timestamp_start  UInt64,
        timestamp_end  UInt64,
        ip_prot_ver UInt8,
        in_phys_int UInt32,
        dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        out_phys_int UInt32,
        post_dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        post_dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        in_vrfid UInt16,
        packets UInt32,
        bytes UInt32
    )
    ENGINE = Kafka () 
    SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 
      'brokers',
      kafka_topic_list = 'avro_test',
      kafka_group_name = 'test1',
      kafka_num_consumers = 8,
      kafka_thread_per_consumer = 4,
      kafka_format = 'Avro',
      kafka_skip_broken_messages = 1,
      kafka_max_block_size = 524288,
      kafka_schema = 'schema.avsc'

REATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.avro ON CLUSTER "ch-cluster" (
                                    mac_src String,
                                    mac_dst String,
                                    peer_ip_src String,
                                    ip_src String,
                                    ip_dst String,
                                    port_src UInt16,
                                    port_dst UInt16,
                                    tcp_flags UInt16,
                                    ip_proto UInt8,
                                    timestamp_start DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
                                    timestamp_end DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
                                    ip_prot_ver UInt8,
                                    in_phys_int UInt32,
                                    dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
                                    dot1q_vlan UInt16,
                                    out_phys_int UInt32,
                                    post_dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
                                    post_dot1q_vlan UInt16,
                                    in_vrfid UInt16,
                                    packets UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1)),
                                    bytes UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1)),
                                    sampling_key UInt32 MATERIALIZED rand32() )
                                ENGINE = MergeTree
                                PARTITION BY toMonday(toDateTime(timestamp_start))
                                ORDER BY (toStartOfFiveMinute(toDateTime(timestamp_start)), sampling_key)
                                SAMPLE BY sampling_key
                                TTL toDateTime(timestamp_start) + toIntervalMonth(8)
                                SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.avro_dview ON CLUSTER "ch-cluster" (  
        mac_src String,
        mac_dst String,
        peer_ip_src String,
        ip_src String,
        ip_dst String,
        port_src UInt16,
        port_dst UInt16,
        tcp_flags UInt16,
        ip_proto UInt8,
        timestamp_start DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
        timestamp_end DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
        ip_prot_ver UInt8,
        in_phys_int UInt32,
        dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        out_phys_int UInt32,
        post_dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        post_dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        in_vrfid UInt16,
        packets UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1)),
        bytes UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1)),
        sampling_key UInt32 MATERIALIZED rand32() )
    ENGINE = Distributed(ch-cluster,default,avro,murmurHash3_64(in_phys_int));

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS default.avro_mview ON CLUSTER "ch-cluster" TO avro_dview
(
        mac_src String,
        mac_dst String,
        peer_ip_src String,
        ip_src String,
        ip_dst String,
        port_src UInt16,
        port_dst UInt16,
        tcp_flags UInt16,
        ip_proto UInt8,
        timestamp_start DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
        timestamp_end DateTime64(3, 'Europe/Berlin'),
        ip_prot_ver UInt8,
        in_phys_int UInt32,
        dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        out_phys_int UInt32,
        post_dot1q_cvlan UInt16,
        post_dot1q_vlan UInt16,
        in_vrfid UInt16,
        packets UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1)),
        bytes UInt32 CODEC(T64, ZSTD(1))
) AS
SELECT
        mac_src,
        mac_dst,
        peer_ip_src,
        ip_src,
        ip_dst,
        port_src,
        port_dst,
        tcp_flags,
        ip_proto,
        timestamp_start,
        timestamp_end,
        ip_prot_ver,
        in_phys_int,
        dot1q_cvlan,
        dot1q_vlan,
        out_phys_int,
        post_dot1q_cvlan,
        post_dot1q_vlan,
        in_vrfid,
        packets,
        bytes
FROM default.kafka_avro_consumer
```

Because of performance reasons I don't want to use a Schema Registry..

Does anybody has an idea ?

Many thanks in advance and best regards..

Comment: From docs - "ClickHouse Avro format supports reading and writing **Avro data files**". Or as error says "Invalid data **file**" ... You might have better luck with protobuf or msgpack if you must use a binary format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :).. do you mean that avro is not working properly in CH ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It works, as is documented. You cannot (easily) put "Avro object container data files" into Kafka. Also, Schema Registry wouldn't have significant performance impact because schemas get cached when requested